# Publish in wordpress when a Wix site is updated

Tags: php, wordpress, velo, ifttt

What I need is somewhat peculiar, on my Wordpress Web I want to publish a series of news copied from another Web (this is already agreed and the source of the news will be shown). I know how to create posts and how to extract HTML with PHP, but I can't find the method to run it when a new post is published. The Web is created in Wix, therefore IFTTT does not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: it is not clear to me, what you want to achieve. Please add some details, what is not working and what you have tried so far. `but I can't find the method to run it when a new post is published` There is the `the_post` [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/), which gets fired, when a new post is processed. But I think you wanna do some timed execution, which will need something like `cron`.

Comment: I think you should integrate Rest API of WordPress for doing it. 
You just need some authorization and some Skills to integrate it.

Comment: What I need is to publish a post in Wordpress when it is published on a website created with Wix. That is, duplicate the posts on my Wordpress website.

Comment: @angelvilu I got it so i said to it can be carried out from the Rest API with your access. Please go throught the documentation of the WordPress Rest API.

Comment: No idea how the Wordpress REST API works, I've never had to use it and I don't know where to start to do what I need. On the other hand it is true that I can do a CRON task, but I still do not know how to discriminate a new post from an old one, I need to publish the new ones because if not every time the task is executed it will publish all the existing posts.